# Angular cli 6 installation error

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

When I am running this command,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I am getting this error,

> ```
>     npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...npackedSize":87169,"n'    
>     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     C:\Users\Krishanu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-26T09_25_38_336Z-debug.log
> ```

I am on a windows system. Thing is that this was working on the linux a day before, now on linux i cannot create any app,

```
ng new ngapp
```

this command is showing the same error. I tried switching to a different network, but not working. I also tried updating the `node` and `npm`.

I am new to angular programming and I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Try `—verbose` flag and give the output here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to the cache, try the following,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then do

```
ng new app
```

Answer (score 1):

use => npm update --save with administrator permission